# Using vagrant with berkshelf and chef-solo : Try to install apt and apache2

Tags: apache, vagrant, chef-infra, chef-solo, berkshelf

From https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/chef_solo.html and http://berkshelf.com/, I'm trying to add **apt** and **apache2** recipes.

My settings :

- Host OS : Windows 10
- vagrant : v1.8.1
- Virtualbox : v5.0.14
- Guest OS : Ubuntu Precise64 (default vagrant VM)

My different steps:

1) Set up vagrant plug-ins:

- vagrant plugin install vagrant-berkshelf
- vagrant plugin install vagrant-omnibus
- vagrant plugin install vagrant-hostmanager

Installed versions:

```
$ vagrant plugin list
vagrant-berkshelf (4.1.0)
vagrant-hostmanager (1.8.2)
vagrant-omnibus (1.4.1)
vagrant-share (1.1.5, system)
```

2) Set up **Chef dk 0.15.15** on the host (Necessary to start a vagrant VM with the Berkshelf plugin)

3) **Vagrantfile** file config

```
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"

  config.omnibus.chef_version = :latest
  config.berkshelf.enabled = true

  config.vm.provision "chef_solo" do |chef|
    chef.add_recipe "apt"
    chef.add_recipe "apache2"
  end
```

4) Create manually the **Berksfile** file (in the same folder as Vagrantfile)

```
source "https://supermarket.chef.io"

cookbook "apt"
cookbook "apache2"
```

After doing these settings, I can do the vagrant up to start the machine.

```
vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Loading Berkshelf datafile...
==> default: Sharing cookbooks with VM
==> default: Checking if box 'hashicorp/precise64' is up to date...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Updating Vagrant's Berkshelf...
==> default: Resolving cookbook dependencies...
==> default: Using apache2 (3.2.2)
==> default: Using apt (4.0.1)
==> default: Using compat_resource (12.10.6)
==> default: Vendoring apache2 (3.2.2) to C:/Users/No/.berkshelf/vagrant-berkshelf/shelves/berkshelf20160630-13400-d00zd2-default/apache2
==> default: Vendoring apt (4.0.1) to C:/Users/No/.berkshelf/vagrant-berkshelf/shelves/berkshelf20160630-13400-d00zd2-default/apt
==> default: Vendoring compat_resource (12.10.6) to C:/Users/No/.berkshelf/vagrant-berkshelf/shelves/berkshelf20160630-13400-d00zd2-default/compat_resource
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
    default: The guest additions on this VM do not match the installed version of
    default: VirtualBox! In most cases this is fine, but in rare cases it can
    default: prevent things such as shared folders from working properly. If you see
    default: shared folder errors, please make sure the guest additions within the
    default: virtual machine match the version of VirtualBox you have installed on
    default: your host and reload your VM.
    default:
    default: Guest Additions Version: 4.2.0
    default: VirtualBox Version: 5.0
==> default: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /vagrant => D:/Vagrant VMs Files/Linux/Ubuntu Standard/v12.04 LTS Precise/Hashicorp-Precise64 - Template (TUTO)
    default: /tmp/vagrant-chef/83b8a9c0ce916541f1e94cb0043abcfa/cookbooks => C:/Users/No/.berkshelf/vagrant-berkshelf/shelves/berkshelf20160630-13400-d00zd2-default
==> default: Machine already provisioned. Run `vagrant provision` or use the `--provision`
==> default: flag to force provisioning. Provisioners marked to run always will still run.
```

And then doing a vagrant provision

```
vagrant provision
==> default: Loading Berkshelf datafile...
==> default: Sharing cookbooks with VM
==> default: Updating Vagrant's Berkshelf...
==> default: Resolving cookbook dependencies...
==> default: Using apache2 (3.2.2)
==> default: Using apt (4.0.1)
==> default: Using compat_resource (12.10.6)
==> default: Vendoring apache2 (3.2.2) to C:/Users/No/.berkshelf/vagrant-berkshelf/shelves/berkshelf20160630-13400-d00zd2-default/apache2
==> default: Vendoring apt (4.0.1) to C:/Users/No/.berkshelf/vagrant-berkshelf/shelves/berkshelf20160630-13400-d00zd2-default/apt
==> default: Vendoring compat_resource (12.10.6) to C:/Users/No/.berkshelf/vagrant-berkshelf/shelves/berkshelf20160630-13400-d00zd2-default/compat_resource
==> default: Chef 12.11.18 Omnibus package is already installed.
==> default: Running provisioner: chef_solo...
==> default: Detected Chef (latest) is already installed
==> default: Generating chef JSON and uploading...
==> default: Running chef-solo...
==> default: stdin: is not a tty
==> default: [2016-06-30T07:06:10+00:00] INFO: Started chef-zero at chefzero://localhost:8889 with repository at /tmp/vagrant-chef/83b8a9c0ce916541f1e94cb0043abcfa
==> default:   One version per cookbook
==> default: [2016-06-30T07:06:10+00:00] INFO: Forking chef instance to converge...
==> default: Starting Chef Client, version 12.11.18
==> default: [2016-06-30T07:06:10+00:00] INFO: *** Chef 12.11.18 ***
==> default: [2016-06-30T07:06:10+00:00] INFO: Platform: x86_64-linux
==> default: [2016-06-30T07:06:10+00:00] INFO: Chef-client pid: 1377
==> default: [2016-06-30T07:06:13+00:00] INFO: GET /organizations/chef/nodes/vagrant-084b5399
==> default: [2016-06-30T07:06:13+00:00] INFO: #<ChefZero::RestErrorResponse: 404: Object not found: chefzero://localhost:8889/nodes/vagrant-084b5399>
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-zero-4.6.2/lib/chef_zero/rest_base.rb:91:in `rescue in get_data'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-zero-4.6.2/lib/chef_zero/rest_base.rb:83:in `get_data'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-zero-4.6.2/lib/chef_zero/endpoints/rest_object_endpoint.rb:18:in `get'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-zero-4.6.2/lib/chef_zero/rest_base.rb:62:in `call'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-zero-4.6.2/lib/chef_zero/rest_router.rb:24:in `call'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-zero-4.6.2/lib/chef_zero/server.rb:664:in `block in app'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-zero-4.6.2/lib/chef_zero/server.rb:336:in `call'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-zero-4.6.2/lib/chef_zero/server.rb:336:in `handle_socketless_request'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-zero-4.6.2/lib/chef_zero/socketless_server_map.rb:87:in `request'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-zero-4.6.2/lib/chef_zero/socketless_server_map.rb:33:in `request'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.18/lib/chef/http/socketless_chef_zero_client.rb:154:in `request'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.18/lib/chef/http.rb:305:in `block in send_http_request'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.18/lib/chef/http.rb:336:in `block in retrying_http_errors'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.18/lib/chef/http.rb:334:in `loop'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.18/lib/chef/http.rb:334:in `retrying_http_errors'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.18/lib/chef/http.rb:299:in `send_http_request'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.18/lib/chef/http.rb:144:in `request'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.18/lib/chef/http.rb:111:in `get'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.18/lib/chef/node.rb:604:in `load'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.18/lib/chef/node.rb:588:in `find_or_create'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.18/lib/chef/policy_builder/dynamic.rb:72:in `load_node'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.18/lib/chef/client.rb:467:in `load_node'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.18/lib/chef/client.rb:269:in `run'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.18/lib/chef/application.rb:286:in `block in fork_chef_client'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.18/lib/chef/application.rb:274:in `fork'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.18/lib/chef/application.rb:274:in `fork_chef_client'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.18/lib/chef/application.rb:239:in `block in run_chef_client'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.18/lib/chef/local_mode.rb:44:in `with_server_connectivity'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.18/lib/chef/application.rb:227:in `run_chef_client'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.18/lib/chef/application/client.rb:456:in `sleep_then_run_chef_client'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.18/lib/chef/application/client.rb:443:in `block in interval_run_chef_client'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.18/lib/chef/application/client.rb:442:in `loop'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.18/lib/chef/application/client.rb:442:in `interval_run_chef_client'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.18/lib/chef/application/client.rb:426:in `run_application'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.18/lib/chef/application.rb:59:in `run'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.18/lib/chef/application/solo.rb:217:in `run'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.18/bin/chef-solo:25:in `<top (required)>'
==> default: /usr/bin/chef-solo:52:in `load'
==> default: /usr/bin/chef-solo:52:in `<main>'
==> default: [2016-06-30T07:06:13+00:00] INFO: HTTP Request Returned 404 Not Found: Object not found: chefzero://localhost:8889/nodes/vagrant-084b5399
==> default: [2016-06-30T07:06:13+00:00] INFO: POST /organizations/chef/nodes
==> default: --- POST BODY ---
==> default: {"name":"vagrant-084b5399","chef_environment":"_default","json_class":"Chef::Node","automatic":{},"normal":{},"chef_type":"node","default":{},"override":{},"run_list":[]}
==> default: --- END POST BODY ---
==> default: [2016-06-30T07:06:13+00:00] INFO: #<ChefZero::RestErrorResponse: 404: Parent not found: chefzero://localhost:8889/nodes>
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-zero-4.6.2/lib/chef_zero/rest_base.rb:187:in `rescue in create_data'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-zero-4.6.2/lib/chef_zero/rest_base.rb:181:in `create_data'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-zero-4.6.2/lib/chef_zero/endpoints/rest_list_endpoint.rb:31:in `post'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-zero-4.6.2/lib/chef_zero/endpoints/nodes_endpoint.rb:24:in `post'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-zero-4.6.2/lib/chef_zero/rest_base.rb:62:in `call'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-zero-4.6.2/lib/chef_zero/rest_router.rb:24:in `call'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-zero-4.6.2/lib/chef_zero/server.rb:664:in `block in app'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-zero-4.6.2/lib/chef_zero/server.rb:336:in `call'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-zero-4.6.2/lib/chef_zero/server.rb:336:in `handle_socketless_request'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-zero-4.6.2/lib/chef_zero/socketless_server_map.rb:87:in `request'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-zero-4.6.2/lib/chef_zero/socketless_server_map.rb:33:in `request'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.18/lib/chef/http/socketless_chef_zero_client.rb:154:in `request'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.18/lib/chef/http.rb:305:in `block in send_http_request'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.18/lib/chef/http.rb:336:in `block in retrying_http_errors'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.18/lib/chef/http.rb:334:in `loop'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.18/lib/chef/http.rb:334:in `retrying_http_errors'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.18/lib/chef/http.rb:299:in `send_http_request'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.18/lib/chef/http.rb:144:in `request'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.18/lib/chef/http.rb:127:in `post'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.18/lib/chef/node.rb:639:in `create'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.18/lib/chef/node.rb:592:in `rescue in find_or_create'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.18/lib/chef/node.rb:588:in `find_or_create'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.18/lib/chef/policy_builder/dynamic.rb:72:in `load_node'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.18/lib/chef/client.rb:467:in `load_node'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.18/lib/chef/client.rb:269:in `run'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.18/lib/chef/application.rb:286:in `block in fork_chef_client'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.18/lib/chef/application.rb:274:in `fork'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.18/lib/chef/application.rb:274:in `fork_chef_client'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.18/lib/chef/application.rb:239:in `block in run_chef_client'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.18/lib/chef/local_mode.rb:44:in `with_server_connectivity'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.18/lib/chef/application.rb:227:in `run_chef_client'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.18/lib/chef/application/client.rb:456:in `sleep_then_run_chef_client'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.18/lib/chef/application/client.rb:443:in `block in interval_run_chef_client'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.18/lib/chef/application/client.rb:442:in `loop'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.18/lib/chef/application/client.rb:442:in `interval_run_chef_client'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.18/lib/chef/application/client.rb:426:in `run_application'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.18/lib/chef/application.rb:59:in `run'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.18/lib/chef/application/solo.rb:217:in `run'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.18/bin/chef-solo:25:in `<top (required)>'
==> default: /usr/bin/chef-solo:52:in `load'
==> default: /usr/bin/chef-solo:52:in `<main>'
==> default: [2016-06-30T07:06:13+00:00] INFO: HTTP Request Returned 404 Not Found: Parent not found: chefzero://localhost:8889/nodes
==> default: ================================================================================
==> default: Chef encountered an error attempting to load the node data for "vagrant-084b5399"
==> default: ================================================================================
==> default:
==> default: Resource Not Found:
==> default: -------------------
==> default: The server returned a HTTP 404. This usually indicates that your chef_server_url is incorrect.
==> default: Relevant Config Settings:
==> default: -------------------------
==> default: chef_server_url "chefzero://localhost:8889"
==> default: Platform:
==> default: ---------
==> default: x86_64-linux
==> default:
==> default: Running handlers:
==> default: [2016-06-30T07:06:13+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
==> default: Running handlers complete
==> default: [2016-06-30T07:06:13+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
==> default: Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 02 seconds
==> default: [2016-06-30T07:06:13+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
==> default: [2016-06-30T07:06:13+00:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
==> default: [2016-06-30T07:06:13+00:00] ERROR: 404 "Not Found"
==> default: [2016-06-30T07:06:14+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
Chef never successfully completed! Any errors should be visible in the
output above. Please fix your recipes so that they properly complete.
```

As you can see, I have some errors (**Chef encountered an error attempting to load the node data for "vagrant-084b5399"**), please see the chef-stacktrace.out file content below

```
Generated at 2016-06-30 07:06:13 +0000
Net::HTTPServerException: 404 "Not Found"
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/response.rb:119:in `error!'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.18/lib/chef/http.rb:146:in `request'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.18/lib/chef/http.rb:127:in `post'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.18/lib/chef/node.rb:639:in `create'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.18/lib/chef/node.rb:592:in `rescue in find_or_create'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.18/lib/chef/node.rb:588:in `find_or_create'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.18/lib/chef/policy_builder/dynamic.rb:72:in `load_node'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.18/lib/chef/client.rb:467:in `load_node'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.18/lib/chef/client.rb:269:in `run'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.18/lib/chef/application.rb:286:in `block in fork_chef_client'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.18/lib/chef/application.rb:274:in `fork'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.18/lib/chef/application.rb:274:in `fork_chef_client'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.18/lib/chef/application.rb:239:in `block in run_chef_client'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.18/lib/chef/local_mode.rb:44:in `with_server_connectivity'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.18/lib/chef/application.rb:227:in `run_chef_client'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.18/lib/chef/application/client.rb:456:in `sleep_then_run_chef_client'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.18/lib/chef/application/client.rb:443:in `block in interval_run_chef_client'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.18/lib/chef/application/client.rb:442:in `loop'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.18/lib/chef/application/client.rb:442:in `interval_run_chef_client'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.18/lib/chef/application/client.rb:426:in `run_application'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.18/lib/chef/application.rb:59:in `run'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.18/lib/chef/application/solo.rb:217:in `run'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.18/bin/chef-solo:25:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/bin/chef-solo:52:in `load'
/usr/bin/chef-solo:52:in `<main>'
```

I have verified, apache2 is not installed on the VM.

I don't know what these errors mean, is there a mistake somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to upgrade your Vagrant, the latest is 1.8.4. We made some changes to how chef-solo works internally that Vagrant had to adjust to.

Comment: That works fine after updating vagrant to v1.8.4. Thanks